# How to express that instructions (i.e. a recipe) should be followed precisely?

Tags: phrase-request, idioms

Suppose I'm giving a recipe (let's say, for a special cake) to a friend. I'd like to make sure he follows the recipe precisely down to the last minute detail.

Is there an idiom that I could use to express this? As in, "But you have to follow the instructions of the recipe **___**!"?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[*To the letter*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/to+the+letter) is often used here.

> exactly as instructed; exactly as written.

One of the examples on The Free Dictionary is even about a cake recipe:

> *We didn't prepare the recipe to the letter, but the cake still turned out very well.*

Answer (score 2):

"To a 'T' " is another saying, but 'To the letter is the better answer'.